# fire ng-change function on select option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a weird query here. Please refer to this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ctbLparv/

```
<select ng-model="bob" ng-click="test()">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

As you can see in this fiddle, i have options 5,10 and 15. If user selects 10 or 15, ng-change event gets triggered and an alert message pops up. As you noticed 5 is selected by default here and shows up initially.

What if i want to trigger ng-change by selecting 5 itself. It doesnt work. Obviously it wont work because we are selecting the value 5 and it was the same value as earlier. hence ng-change wont trigger. I get this point.

but i have a scenario, where i want to trigger a function when the user selects the default value again. Can someone please help me in this.

PS- i cant use ng-click because it fires the event as soon as we click on the option tags itself. so it doesnot allow u to select from a dropdown and straight away fires an event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-change` to call a function in your controller that looks at your selected option and determines if it is the default option. Anytime a user selects the default option, you can call whatever code you would like.

**Example (HTML):**

```
<select
    ng-change='myChangeFunction()' 
    ng-model="mySelectedOption"
    ng-options="myOptions">
</select>
```

**Example (JS):**

```
$scope.myOptions = [
    { id: "5", name: "5" },
    { id: "10", name: "10" },
    { id: "15", name: "15" }
];

$scope.myChangeFunction = function() {
    if($scope.mySelectedOption.id === 5) {
        // Default value has been selected, call your function
    }
};
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for what you're code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

**`ng-change/watch`** works only when the model is changed, Alternatively you can use ng-selected directive,

```
 <select ng-model="bob" ng-selected="test()">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ctbLparv/)

Comment: This is completely inaccurate.
The `ng-selected` directive is for conditionally adding the `selected` attribute. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the ng-model value to your function.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="bob" ng-click="test(bob)">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.test = function (value) {
 alert ("changed to "+ value);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this might help you.

```
<select ng-model="bob" ng-change="test()">
  <option disabled value="">Select value ...</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Here i have created one more option which is disabled and used as a placeholder to select options. Which you might not need to trigger the option with value 5 again.

Please check in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yashwanth_t/ctbLparv/65/) for any doubts.

Hope this is helpful. Thank you.